# Not getting proper output in outlook of basic html code with table tags

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table

I am trying to make a template, which I want to use with outlook, but when I use this code, i am getting logo at right and link text left in outlook, which is total oppose to which output I want. How do I resolve it?

```
<center>
<table width="600px;" style="margin:auto auto;">
<tr style="left:auto">
<td>
```

In this main table's td tag below mentioned tables are included.. I also check that all tags are closed properly without forget any single tag.

This code is for logo and link's main table...

```
<table width="150px;" bgcolor="ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
```

this code for link

```
<td style="text-align:right;">
<a href="http://www.url.com" target="_blank">
<span style="font-family:Myriad Pro; color:#0d5497; font-size:20px; text-align:end; inline-box-align:last; left:auto" data->www.linkurl.com
</span>
</td>
```

I had also used text-align, left:auto, right:auto in

```
<table> <tr> <td>
```

level accordingly but not getting proper output.

Image of output in outlook

[image: Image of output in outlook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more towards what you are looking for here: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5kfGY/2/)

You had the right idea with

```
<td style="text-align:right;">
<a href="http://www.url.com" target="_blank">
<span style="font-family:Myriad Pro; color:#0d5497; font-size:20px; text-align:end; inline-box-align:last; left:auto" data->www.linkurl.com
</span>
</td>
```

but some of your css looks a little off. Text-align doesn't have an 'end' value and I had never heard of inline-box-align before.